# Getting the product in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

Can I ask why the multiplication function is not working properly? What can I do to make it work?

```
org 100h



 .MODEL SMALL
.STACK
.DATA
    MSG1    DB  10,13,  'Enter First Number: $'
    MSG2    DB  10,13,  'Enter Second Number: $'
    MSG3    DB  10,13,  'SUM: $'
    MSG4    DB  10,13,  'DIFFERENCE: $'
    MSG5    DB  10,13,  'PRODUCT: $'
    MSG6    DB  10,13,  'QUOTIENT: $'
    NEGA    DB  '-$'

    NUM1    DB  0
    NUM2    DB  0
    DIG1    DB  0
    DIG2    DB  0
    ANS     DB  0

.CODE

MAIN PROC
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX

ENT1:
    MOV DX,OFFSET MSG1  ;display prompt for first number
    MOV AH,09H
    int 21h

    MOV AH,01H      ;input first number
    INT 21H

    

    SUB AL,30H      ;convert to real number entered
    MOV DIG1,AL

    MOV AH,01H      ;input first number
    INT 21H

   

    SUB AL,30H      ;convert to real number entered
    MOV DIG2,AL

    MOV AL,DIG1     ;convert 1st digit to tens place
    MOV BL,10
    MUL BL

    MOV NUM1,AL     ;add 1st digit to 2nd digit
    MOV AL,DIG2
    ADD NUM1,AL


ENT2:
    MOV DX,OFFSET MSG2  ;display prompt for second number
    MOV AH,09H
    int 21h

    MOV AH,01H      ;input second number
    INT 21H

    

    SUB AL,30H      ; convert to real number entered
    MOV DIG1,AL

    MOV AH,01H      ;input second number
    INT 21H

    

    SUB AL,30H      ;convert to real number entered
    MOV DIG2,AL

    MOV AL,DIG1
    MOV BL,10
    MUL BL

    MOV NUM2,AL
    MOV AL,DIG2
    ADD NUM2,AL


ADDITION:
    MOV BL,NUM1
    ADD BL,NUM2

    CALL CHANGE

    MOV DX,OFFSET MSG3
    CALL RESULT

SUBTRACTION:
    MOV BL, NUM1
    CMP BL, NUM2
    

    SUB BL, NUM2

    CALL CHANGE

    MOV DX,OFFSET MSG4
    CALL RESULT     

;MULTIPLICATION

    MOV AL, NUM1
    IMUL NUM2
    MOV ANS, AL

CALL CHANGE

MOV DX, OFFSET MSG5
CALL RESULT   

;DIVISION 

 



CHANGE PROC
    MOV AH,0
    MOV AL,BL

    MOV BL,10
    DIV BL

    MOV BL,AL
    MOV BH,AH

    ADD BH,30H      ; convert to ascii code
    MOV ANS,BH

    MOV AH,0
    MOV AL,BL
    MOV BL,10
    DIV BL

    MOV BL,AL
    MOV BH,AH

    ADD BH,30h      ; convert to ascii code
    ADD BL, 30h     ; covert to ascii code

    RET
CHANGE ENDP


RESULT PROC

    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H

    MOV DL,BL
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H

    MOV DL,BH
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H

    MOV DL,ANS
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H

    RET
RESULT ENDP


END
```

Comment: “Not working properly” is not an error description.  Please say what behaviour you expect and what happened instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying, my problem is that I am getting a wrong product, the product that I always get is the value "num1"

Comment: Please post a sample session of your program.

Comment: `ADD BH, 30H; MOV ANS, BH` looks fishy.  Should it perhaps be the other way round?

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand. What do you mean by posting a session of my program?

Comment: Post an example of input you provide to the program and the output it returns.  Also say what output you expected instead of the output the program gives.

Comment: (INPUT)
First Number:15
Second Number: 05

(EXPECTED OUTPUT)
Product: 75

(OUTPUT that the program gives)
Product: 15

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: `mov  ax, 5` sets ax = 5,
`mov  cx, 10` sets cx = 10,
`mul  cx` results in dx:ax = ax * cx _ or_ ax = al * cl. When in asm doubt, check http://www.sandpile.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHANGE expects the result in BL, but IMUL puts the result in AL.